# Uncontrollable jumping - sIFR lagging

Tags: flash, sifr, image-replacement

sIFR-replaced text shows normally, hiding regular text without issue. However, every time a page loads on the site I'm developing, the replaced text takes forever (forever in internet-time, that is) to load, and jumps vertically on the page with a long lag before finally settling into place.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll just switch to Cufon. That solution didn't help me at all - and I see this very same question asked frequently with no definitive, 100% effective solution. Decreasing the load time doesn't help with the jumping, either, which is another sIFR issue I see constantly on message boards and the like.